# Is it possible to create shape keys for hands that are rigged with an armature?

Tags: armature

I’m attempting to create several
Poses and movements with the hand, or hands; which are attach to the same armature… Like a first person shooter.

However, I’d like to transition each pose; into another pose, or from choices; within a collection of pose types.

(I was attempting to do this with shape keys, but shape keys don’t seem to work with hand armatures. Or perhaps it’s because of IK FK? Now I’m confusing myself. Maybe I’m wrong about this… Correct me if I am.)

Comment: pls provide example blend file so we see what you have done and how we can help. thx

Comment: Shape keys move the vertices of the mesh in a straight way. You cannot use them to create an arc or bending. Together with a rig, they are used to correct mesh deformation, for example, to maintain volume and do little corrections. If you want to create transitions between poses try the [NLA editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/nla/index.html) and the [Pose Library](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/posing/editing/pose_library.html) (requires Blender 3.0).